# PHP MySQL Query "Create Table" - beginner needs assistance

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple database table using the PHP MySQL query "Create Table", but it's not working.

What is wrong with the below code?

```
 // Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost","the_database_name","the_database_password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("the_database_name") or die(mysql_error());

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE downloads_list(
download_id INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
download_date TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
visitor_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
visitor_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
visitor_email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
visitor_phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
store_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
document_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (download_id)")
 or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";
```

Comment: Have you verified the SQL executes successfully on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're not closing the paren you opened just after `download_list`.

Comment: It seems like the paren I opened just after download_list is closed here: "or die(mysql_error()); ". Is that right?

Comment: no you never actually closed that paren. infact a decent editor ought to highlight that for you

Comment: Where should the close paren go? I'm using Aptana as an editor and my original code is not triggering an error.

Comment: is this the correct spot to add the missing paren? "PRIMARY KEY (download_id))")" .... I'm referring to the second close paren

Comment: Yes Alex, your answer is correct and the "spot" I previously mentioned was the fix. This was a huge help.